# Berkshelf directory name from github cookbook

Tags: github, tags, version, chef-infra, berkshelf

My custom cookbooks are stored in private github repos.  When adding them to a Berkshelf project, they are added to `.berkshelf/cookbooks` as `custom-cookbook-commit-number` instead of `custom-cookbook-version-number`

My github repo has tags with the version.  "Releases" has all of the version tags listed.

What do I need to change so the cookbooks become
`.berkshelf/cookbooks/custom-cookbook-version-number`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the path location instead of git location in your `Berksfile` please:

```
cookbook "artifact", path: "/Users/reset/code/artifact-cookbook"
```

Then you need to clone your private cookbook from gitrepo and make sure they're up to date.

Comment: When using the path directive, the cookbook is not added to my Berksfile directory.  Is that correct?

Comment: correct. checkout the details from [Path location](http://berkshelf.com/#path_location)